# C# and EPPlus, writing text values from form to next available empty row

Tags: c#, loops, visual-studio-2017, epplus

So I'm playing around with EPPlus and C# and I have a form with some text fields, and I'm trying to add the text field values to the next available empty row and I'm having some trouble.  I have tried several different ways to find the next available empty row to append the text field values to that row always skipping the first row since it has my Column Headers.

The closest I have come was to get it to constantly write to row 2 and 3 but it would always write the same info.

```
//create an instance of the first sheet in the loaded file
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

var r = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++)
{
     worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = comboBox1.Text;
     worksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value = textBox1.Text;
     worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = textBox2.Text;
     worksheet.Cells[i, 4].Value = textBox3.Text;
     worksheet.Cells[i, 5].Value = textBox4.Text;
     worksheet.Cells[i, 6].Value = richTextBox1.Text;
}
```

Here is all of my code in case you need to see how or what I'm working with.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;

namespace NetworkManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@".\Owners.txt");
            string x = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] y = x.Split('\n');
            foreach (string s in y)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }

        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new blank package/file
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage()) 
            {
                // Add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                // Set the header text 
                worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddHeader.CenteredText = "&24&U&\"Arial,Regular Bold\" Router IP" + textBox5;

                //Set column width
                worksheet.Column(1).Width = 20;
                worksheet.Column(2).Width = 25;
                worksheet.Column(3).Width = 20;
                worksheet.Column(4).Width = 25;
                worksheet.Column(5).Width = 25;
                worksheet.Column(6).Width = 25;

                // Border and Font for Column Headers
                worksheet.Cells["A1:F1"].Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thick);  // Thick border around Column Headers
                worksheet.Cells["A1:F1"].Style.Font.Bold = true; // Bold text for Column Headers
                worksheet.Cells["A1:F1"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;


                //Add column headers
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Owner";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Device Name";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Ip Address";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Mac Address 1";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Mac Address 2";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Notes";


                // set some document properties
                package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "NetworkManager";
                package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "David Goodwin";
                package.Workbook.Properties.Comments = "This is a program to help manager your network addresses";

                //Save your file
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@".\ExportedDoc\NetworkManager.xlsx");
                package.SaveAs(fi);

                MessageBox.Show("New File Created!");
            }
        }

        private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Append data to already existing excel document
        {
            //the path of the file
            string filePath = ".\\ExportedDoc\\NetworkManager.xlsx";

            //create a fileinfo object of an excel file on the disk
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

            //create a new Excel package from the file
            using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {
                //create an instance of the first sheet in the loaded file
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];



                var r = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = comboBox1.Text;
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value = textBox1.Text;
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = textBox2.Text;
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 4].Value = textBox3.Text;
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 5].Value = textBox4.Text;
                    worksheet.Cells[i, 6].Value = richTextBox1.Text;
                }


                /*
                // check to find last empty row to add new rows.
                int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                    // Create a bool
                    bool RowIsEmpty = true;

                    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                    {
                        // check if the cell is empty or not
                        if (worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value != null)
                        {
                            RowIsEmpty = false;
                        }
                    }

                    // if row is empty, hit flag and write data 
                    if (RowIsEmpty == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Test");
                        // write data to next available row
                        int i = 1;
                        foreach (var item in worksheet.Cells)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[1, i].Value = comboBox1.Text;
                            worksheet.Cells[2, i].Value = textBox1.Text;
                            worksheet.Cells[3, i].Value = textBox2.Text;
                            worksheet.Cells[4, i].Value = textBox3.Text;
                            worksheet.Cells[5, i].Value = textBox4.Text;
                            worksheet.Cells[6, i].Value = richTextBox1.Text;
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                */
                /*
                // add some data
                worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = comboBox1.Text;
                worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = textBox1.Text;
                worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = textBox2.Text;
                worksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = textBox3.Text;
                worksheet.Cells["E2"].Value = textBox4.Text;
                worksheet.Cells["F2"].Value = richTextBox1.Text;
                */

                // after adding the items, clear the fields                
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
                textBox3.Clear();
                textBox4.Clear();
                textBox5.Clear();
                richTextBox1.Clear();


                //save the changes
                excelPackage.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this seems to work but I'm not sure if it's as efficient as it could be.  I also tested by manually removing a row in the middle and it still goes to the end of the column which is good, I can look into removing blank rows between row 1 and rowCount.

```
//Cells only contains references to cells with actual data
int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
var cells = worksheet.Cells;
var rowIndicies = cells
    .Select(c => c.Start.Row)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

//Skip the header row
for (var i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)                
{ 
    // add some data
    worksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 1].Value = comboBox1.Text;
    worksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 2].Value = textBox1.Text;
    worksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 3].Value = textBox2.Text;
    worksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 4].Value = textBox3.Text;
    worksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 5].Value = textBox4.Text;
    worksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 6].Value = richTextBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: I'd break out a separate function that takes a worksheet or a range and returns the first empty row. It will be easier to test in isolation.

Comment: So I think i got it to work, but i'm wondering if this is the best way to do it or not.

Comment: You could update the question with your new code.

Comment: Thanks, :D that's what i was trying to do :)

Comment: Separating it into a separate function wouldn't be a bad idea either because I was just thinking about being able to search the cells for a specific IP address and then having the ability to delete the row if its found.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is go to the very bottom of your worksheet and add a single row in with values from the Form controls, you should not need a `for` loop at all.  Something like this should do it:

```
//Cells only contains references to cells with actual data
int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
var cells = worksheet.Cells;

var maxRow = cells
    .Select(c => c.Start.Row)
    .Max();

//Go to the next row after the max
maxRow++;
worksheet.Cells[maxRow, 1].Value = comboBox1.Text;
worksheet.Cells[maxRow, 2].Value = textBox1.Text;
worksheet.Cells[maxRow, 3].Value = textBox2.Text;
worksheet.Cells[maxRow, 4].Value = textBox3.Text;
worksheet.Cells[maxRow, 5].Value = textBox4.Text;
worksheet.Cells[maxRow, 6].Value = richTextBox1.Text;
```

Let me know if I am misunderstanding.